# Which method is invoked by [...] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This code invokes [`Array::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D) with `1`, `2` and `3` as arguments:

```
Array[1, 2, 3] #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

But this doesn't seem to call `Array::[]`:

```
[1, 2, 3] #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

So, which method is invoked by `[...]` in Ruby?

Motivation: I'm trying to stub the method in a test.

Comment: This is Ruby syntax for an array literal; what do you expect to be able to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is literal syntax for an array. It's not a message send. Ruby, like the vast majority of other languages, doesn't allow overloading of literals.

If you need literal overloading, you should use a language which does support it, such as Ioke.